# graphlab in python environment

Tags: python, graphlab

I try to install graphlab in Python environment but I get an error:

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement graphlab-create>=2.1 (from GraphLab-Create-License==2.1) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for graphlab-create>=2.1 (from GraphLab-Create-License==2.1)

I followed the steps in this website: https://turi.com/download/install-graphlab-create-command-line.html?
I get that error for the second option after the last step. I also tried other versions of graphlab create and changed the environment to Python 2.7.

For the first option in the website, I don't get any error, works great. But I want to use graphlab in Python environment. Is there any solution for that error?

Comment: You have "virtualenv"?

Comment: yes I have virtualenv and I activate it with no problem.

Comment: What operating system? In the command, are you replacing the appropriate parts? `pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir https://get.graphlab.com/GraphLab-Create/2.1/**your registered email address here/your product key here**/GraphLab-Create-License.tar.gz`

Comment: I use Windows 10. I replace my email address and product key.